# How do I send brackets "%5B" "%5D" as params on an Ajax Request using GET as method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, get, brackets

Using Ajax and the method GET, I am trying to send an url with brackets, but I am not getting the right encoding of them:

```
Request URL:http://myurl/search.html?_dc=1382510050331&search%5Bpostcode%5D=96231
```

instead of:

```
Request URL:http://myurl/search.html?_dc=1382510050331&search[postcode]=96231
```

Error:

```
Status Code:502 Host not found
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://myulr.lan/fpsearchjson.html',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        "geosearch[postcode]":91111
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log("success");
    },
    failure: function(response){
        console.log("failure");
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Where is the error? %5B and %5D should decode just fine to `[` and `]` resp. in any web server. %xx is used for any character that needs to be encoded.

Comment: Status Code: 502 Host not found.

Comment: can you telnet to the server? `telnet my.server.com 80`

Comment: You are right! the %5B and %5D decode fine.

Comment: I think the dns name is wrong, or that something is messing with the request on the way to the server. Can you reach any part of the server in any way?

Comment: Ja, it was something wrong with the dns and proxy. Would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%5B` and `%5D` are the url-encoded values of `[` and `]`. This should be encoded like it is in your example.

The problem seems to be that you are unable to reach the server. Try to reach the server in any way. Maybe open the URL in your favorite browser or telnet to it: `telnet my.server.com 80`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your Get request though ajax should first convert to ASCII, same problem happen to me I solve it though convert my GET request into ASCII and again decode for use :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape function to encode ,decode your url and parameter. On other side you can easily get that value in original format
for example

```
escape("It's me!") // result: It%27s%20me%21
```